Books on QED with an emphasis on measurement?
Most books I've found about QED seem to focus on calculating probabilities without much mention of how the states corresponding to them are measured.
On the other hand, the books which focus the most on measurement,  like Ballentine's Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development, Peres's  Quantum Theory: Concepts and Methods and Bohm's Quantum Theory focus pretty much exclusively on nonrelativistic Quantum Mechanics, aside from a short section in Bohm dealing with the impossibility of assigning a position probability density to photons or other relativistic particles.

The thing you are asking for is pretty much a misunderstanding of the difficulty of getting QED answers to experimental results. The only thing that QED can help get you, are S matrix elements, and you are supposed to connect between them and experiments. It is pretty much assumed that this bit is the easiest part, and that students understand how to do that, whereas the theoretical computation of those S matrix elements are so difficult that it takes multiple modules just to teach.

In Peres' book "Quantum Theory: Concepts and Methods" on p.17 the author writes:

Moreover, we must interpret the experimental outcomes produced by our equipment. We do that by constructing a theoretical model whereby the behavior of the macroscopic equipment is described by a few degrees of freedom, interacting with those of the microscopic system under observation. We then call this a “measurement” of the microscopic system.

Peres doesn't describe such a model or follow its consequences consistently. Then on p.18 he writes:

As explained at the end of Sect. 1-4, quantum theory, in a strict sense, is nothing more than a set of rules whereby physicists compute probabilities for the outcomes of macroscopic tests.

This is what passes for measurement theory in many books on quantum theory.
This kind of vagueness makes serious discussion of real measurements impossible and books on quantum field theory tend not to treat the topic of measurement at all.
There is a large literature that discusses measurement by treating the measurement device, the measured system and their environment using quantum theory. Interactions that copy information out of a quantum system, including measurements, suppress quantum interference - this is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
Decoherence has been tested experimentally and it is possible to tune it by increasing or decreasing the strength of the interaction. For objects you see in everyday life decoherence tends to lead to systems obeying the laws of classical physics to a good approximation.
Using decoherence theory it is possible to discuss different kinds of measurements including measurements of continuous observables such as quantum fields, see Section 7 of this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0149
There are theoretical and experimental papers about decoherence in QED specifically such as
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9510021
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/ab8efc/meta
